# Apps files directories differences between emulator and device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Why in emultador can see the app directories en `data/data/`

[image]

But in the telephone is emty the directory `data/`

[image]

Comment: As a 2k user, you should have long since read [ask]. Why doesn't this follow it?

Comment: you need to have root access to see /data/data content on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

this is only for devices that are using android M and above it really just a permissions issue cause if you try the same for devices below M it works just like in the emulator.